# What were Lacombe & Laughlin discussing while interrogating Neary?

Tags: dialogue, close-encounters-of-the-third-kind

In **Close Encounters of the Third Kind** (1977),  Neary is being interrogated after his capture near Devils Tower; he is in a small room with Lacombe & Laughlin.

My question relates to this part of the scene:

> **Laughlin:** *[about Roy and Jillian]* The two of you felt compelled to be
>   here?
>
> **Roy:** Yeah, you might say that.
>
> **Laughlin:** *[translating]* What did you expect to find?
>
> **Roy:** An answer. That's not crazy, is it? *[Laughlin and Lacombe speak
>   to each other in French]*...Hold it, hold it, hold it! Is that it? Is
>   that all you're gonna ask me? Well, I got a couple of a thousand, damn
>   questions, you know. I want to speak to someone in charge. I want to
>   lodge a complaint. You have no right to make people crazy...If this is
>   nerve gas, how come I know everything in such detail? I've never been
>   here before. How come I know so much? *[raising his voice]* WHAT THE
>   HELL IS GOING ON AROUND HERE?! WHO THE HELL ARE YOU PEOPLE?!

After Neary says "An answer. That's not crazy, is it?", Lacombe & Laughlin confer over something but the entire dialog is in French and a subtitled translation is not available.

**Would someone please provide a translation of the french dialog in this scene?**

Answer (score 11):

This is my attempt at a transcript:

> Claude Lacombe: Je crois qu'on pourrait les mettre dans l'hélicoptères avec les autres [unintelligible] majeur Walsh.
>
> David Laughlin: Il faudrait peut-être verifier ses crédibilités?
>
> Claude Lacombe: Non, j'ai confiance en mon intuition. Ces gens [unintelligible] choisi au hasard. C'est heureux il n'y en a plein d'autres. Ils n'ont rien d'spécial, ils se ont seulement retrouvé au bonne endroit au bon moment.

Translated (somewhat loosely):

> Claude Lacombe: I think we can put them in the helicopter with the others [unintelligible] Major Walsh.
>
> David Laughlin: Maybe we should check his credibility first?
>
> Claude Lacombe: No, I trust my intuition. These people [unintelligible] chosen at random. We're lucky there aren't more of them. There is nothing special about them, they just happened to be at the right place at the right time.

A native French speaker might be able to discern what they're saying in the places where I couldn't figure out what they're saying, but I think you get the gist of their conversation.